# Accessing an object created by a constructor

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm trying to learn some basic GUI implementation in Java.

I have 2 classes, one which contains a constructor. This constructor creates a new JFrame object.

I'm having trouble with working with this JFrame constructor - I want to change its size, and other operations, but can't figure out how to, after I call the constructor.

Here are both classes, **BmrCalcMain**:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class BmrCalcMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BmrCalcv2 frame = new BmrCalcv2();

        BmrCalcv2.newFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        BmrCalcv2.newFrame.setVisible(true);
        BmrCalcv2.newFrame.setSize(650, 475);
        BmrCalcv2.newFrame.setResizable(false);
    }
}
```

**BmrCalcv2:**

```
package v2;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

public class BmrCalcv2  {

    private JLabel ageLabel;
    private JLabel genderLabel;
    private JLabel img1;
    static JFrame newFrame;

    public BmrCalcv2() {

        newFrame = new JFrame("BMR/TDEE Calculator");
        newFrame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        ageLabel = new JLabel("Age:");
        genderLabel = new JLabel("Gender:");
        img1 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("filesrc/Bodybuilding-icon.png"));

        newFrame.add(ageLabel);
        newFrame.add(genderLabel);
        newFrame.add(img1);
    }
}
```

When I run the application, the JLabels and images from the `BmrCalcv2` class do not appear. I believe this is because in the main class, the use of frame is wrong (I need to use newFrame somehow but if I change frame to newFrame it throws errors).

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Those are the same classes, I think you cut and pasted wrong.

Comment: You posted `BmrCalcMain` twice.

Comment: Why am I getting -1'd?

Comment: Probably because you didn't proof read your question well when posting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Understand that your BmrCalcv2 class uses **TWO** JFrames, not one. One is the instance of the BmrCalcv2 class with extends JFrame, and the other is a private field within the BmrCalcv2's constructor. You should get rid of one or the other to straighten this all out. If you decide to use the variable, then make it a field of the class, not a variable local to the constructor. Or if you want to use the JFrame that your class extends from, then get rid of the newFrame field:

i.e,

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

public class BmrCalcv2 extends JFrame {
    private JLabel ageLabel;
    private JLabel genderLabel;
    private JLabel img1;

    public BmrCalcv2() {
        super("BMR/TDEE Calculator");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        ageLabel = new JLabel("Age:");
        genderLabel = new JLabel("Gender:");
        img1 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("filesrc/Bodybuilding-icon.png"));

        add(ageLabel);
        add(genderLabel);
        add(img1);
    }
}
```

Other side recommendations:

- Usually it's better **not** to set the sizes of components but rather to let the components and the layout managers size themselves.
- Understand that as layout managers go, FlowLayout is not the brightest in the pack, and as your GUI's get more complex, as this one likely will soon, you'll probably want to nest JPanels using more robust layouts.
- None of my Swing GUI's extend JFrame but rather most of them either extend JPanel or are geared towards producing a JPanel, and this way I gain much flexibility since I can place this JPanel anywhere I wish, in a JFrame, a JDialog, a JOptionPane, another JPanel, in a JTabbedPane,.....

Comment: I've removed the "extends JFrame" so I only have one within the constructor, and set a variable outside the constructor "static JFrame newFrame", which is then instantiated with the constructor - "newFrame = new JFrame("BMR/TDEE Calculator")". This seems to have made it work whilst leaving the main class as it is. However it says the variable frame is not in use (because it isn't), but thats fine right? I need that line no matter what to instantiate the new JFrame object/add components.

Comment: @Ftahir192: see edit to answer, -- I did just the opposite as you, but either would work. If you get rid of `extends JFrame`, then you'll need the newFrame variable, but again, consider making it a field of the class.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information. I was initially setting locations of objects myself but learned that this wasn't a good way to go about it. I agree that currently the way FlowLayout organizes the components isn't ideal. What layout manager would you recommend to achieve something of similar calibre to the calculator on this site: http://iifym.com/tdee-calculator/

Comment: @Ftahir192: you will want to use several JPanels, each using its own layout manager, and then nest your JPanels. For a regular calculator, one of the JPanels would be a GridLayout and would hold the buttons. Experiment, see what works best.

Comment: I just edited my code - I declared the JFrame object as a field of the class but instantiated it within the constructor. How does the code look? Anything you suggest?

Comment: @Ftahir192: how does it look to you? Does it work as desired yet?

Comment: I think I need to read some GUI information. I amn't actually sure what the difference is between a JPanel and a JFrame. From what I could gather from a google search, JFrame is the actual window (with the titlebar, etc), and JPanel hosts all the components of the window? Any GUI tutorials you would recommend?

Comment: Yeah it works as desired minus the fact that age, gender and image aren't quite where I want them to be, but I think thats because of the layout manager being used. Just changed it to GridLayout and it looks so much better. I will experiment as you said. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: I was wondering if you could briefly explain what the difference is between JFrame and JPanel? I became slightly lost when you mentioned using several JPanels.

Comment: @Ftahir192: a JPanel is a Swing GUI container that usually holds other Swing components. For instance, if you want to group a bunch of radiobuttons in your GUI, you'd likely create a JPanel, give it a GridLayout, add the JRadioButtons to the JPanel, and then add the JPanel to another component, often another JPanel. A JFrame is the top-most window of a desk-top GUI and is a complex compound component made up of a number of sub-components including a JPanel, called its contentPane which holds the meat of the JFrame -- all its components. You can layer JPanels into other JPanels allowing ...

Comment: @Ftahir192: ... complex layouts that use relatively simple layout managers.

Comment: Ah okay, that makes so much sense now. Thank you very much for taking the time to help me, much appreciated :)